# How to pass items as args lists in map?

Tags: python, dictionary, arguments

This is a piece of my code. Lambda accepts 3 parameters, and I wanted to pass them as a tuple of positional arguments, but apparently `map` supplies them as a single argument.

How can I supply those tuples in the bottom as lists of arguments? (I know I can rewrite the lambda, but it will become not well readable)

```
 adds = map((lambda j, f, a:
      j.join([f.format(i) for i in parse.options[a]]) if parse.options[a] else ''),
      ((' ', ' -not -path "{0}" ', 'exclude'),
      (' -or ', '-path "{0}"', 'include')))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting parens around them

```
adds = map((lambda (j, f, a):
  j.join([f.format(i) for i in parse.options[a]]) if parse.options[a] else ''),
  ((' ', ' -not -path "{0}" ', 'exclude'),
  (' -or ', '-path "{0}"', 'include')))
```

Comment: GREAT! Can't believe it's so simple!

Comment: Note that this approach is not valid in Python > 3.0 where parameter deconstruction of this type is no longer supported.
A function
    f(a, (b, c):
        return a+b+c

needs to be written
    f(a, b_c):
        b, c = b_c
        return a+b+c

Regards,
Rickard

Answer (score 5):

The [`map()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map) description:

> `map(function, iterable, ...)`
>
> Apply function to every item of iterable and return a list of the results. **If additional iterable arguments are passed, function must take that many arguments and is applied to the items from all iterables in parallel**. If one iterable is shorter than another it is assumed to be extended with None items. If function is None, the identity function is assumed; if there are multiple arguments, map() returns a list consisting of tuples containing the corresponding items from all iterables (a kind of transpose operation). The iterable arguments may be a sequence or any iterable object; the result is always a list.

You need to place the arguments in parallel lists or tuples, and pass them to [`map()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map) as 3 iterables.

Comment: Yes, this is correct, but the code (the tuples) will be unreadable.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative is to use itertools.starmap which accepts pre-zipped arguments:

```
adds = itertools.starmap((lambda j, f, a:
    j.join([f.format(i) for i in parse.options[a]]) if parse.options[a] else ''),
    ((' ', ' -not -path "{0}" ', 'exclude'),
    (' -or ', '-path "{0}"', 'include')))
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to rewrite as a list comprehension:

```
adds = [
  j.join([f.format(i) for i in parse.options[a]]) if parse.options[a] else ''
  for j, f, a in
  ((' ', ' -not -path "{0}" ', 'exclude'),
  (' -or ', '-path "{0}"', 'include'))]
```